# Setting python virtual env for VS Code testing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to run my unit tests with `pytest` through VS Code testing section but am struggling to get this to work. I believe I know the issue but I can't find where to correct this.

I have a folder called `tests` which it picks up however when going on the testing tab I get the following error:

```
Pytest Discovery Error [repo]
Error discovering pytest tests: 
No module named pandas.
```

I looked at where it is pointing and it is pointing to the base python installation e.g. Python/Python310/lib/importlib.

I have set a conda env as my default env in folder Anaconda3/envs/my-env yet it is not picking this up or using a virtual env.

I have tried several setting options but nothing has worked. Does anyone know how to configure this to set testing to use a virutal env?